Why do we write $ghg^{-1}$ (in algebra) and $PDP^{-1}$ (in linear algebra) and not $g^{-1}hg$ and $P^{-1}DP$?
Why do we write $ghg^{-1}$ (in algebra) and $PDP^{-1}$ (in linear algebra) and not $g^{-1}hg$ and $P^{-1}DP$?
Conjugation by $g$ is always written $ghg^{-1}$. We could just have easily defined it as $g'^{-1}hg'$ (with $g' := g^{-1}$), which would perhaps seem more natural: Take $g'$, do $h$ to it, then undo $g'$.  Is there a reason we start with the inverse?
Similarly, in linear algebra, the form used always resembles $PDP^{-1}$, when perhaps it would seem more natural to start with a matrix $P'$, multiply by $D$, and use inverse only as the last operation, not the first.  Why do we do it in the other order?
For linear algebra, I can guess that perhaps the reason is when diagonalizing $A$, we want the eigenvectors of $A$ to be columns of $P$, which requires  the $A = PDP^{-1}$ order.  Even when not diagonalizing, we might prefer to think of the matrix decomposition as:

Switch to basis described by $P$
Do the matrix transform
Switch back out of the basis

which would require $PDP^{-1}$ order if the basis are columns of $P$.
Is this explanation correct for linear algebra? And, if so, does it somehow generalize to abstract algebra? Perhaps viewing $g$ as some type of basis or coordinate system, we switch in to $g$ (via $g^{-1}$), do operation $h$, and then switch back out (via $g$)?
Are there other reasons for this order?

You could:  it makes no difference.

@Randall I recognize that any element that can be written as one can be written as the other; my question is "Is there a reason that this order is used, especially when the other order seems more natural?"

It's because we (usually) write functions with the argument on the right, so the "usual" ordering becomes natural.  An Eastern European professor taught me linear algebra from an English text, and we were forever transposing everything to translate between the two.

Most algebra books I have read use $g^{-1}hg$, which aligns nicely when you write things on the right (group action), and let your functions act left-to-right, because $h\mapsto g^{-1}hg$ is a right group action in this setup.

For linear algebra, I think your explanation is the right one (this is what I was explicitly taught, at any rate). For groups I guess it matters less, but why not be consistent?

The main reason is that $g \mapsto (h \mapsto g h g^{-1})$ defines a group homomorphism $G \to \mathrm{Aut}(G)$ (whose image consists of the inner automorphisms of $G$), so $G$ acts on $G$ via conjugation from the left. If we choose $g^{-1} h g$, that would be a right action instead. Of course the theory will not change much, but it is just convenient to take one direction (left) as the default one.
Notice that this assumes that $\mathrm{Aut}(G)$ is given the usual operation of composing functions, which is executed from right to left. If we use the other composition $f\,;\,g$ which is "first $f$ then $g$", then we would get a group homomorphism $G \to \mathrm{Aut}'(G)$ mapping $g \mapsto (h \mapsto g^{-1} h g)$. Notice $\mathrm{Aut}'(G) = \mathrm{Aut}(G)^{op}$.

For a more pedestrian approach, think in terms of group actions. Suppose $G$ acts on $X$.
Fix $g \in G$. Consider the "active transformation" by $g$ that takes each $x \in X$ to $x' = gx \in X$. Now we would like to know what happens to the action of $h \in G$ on the untransformed $X$ in the transformed $X$. Set $y = hx$. Then $g^{-1}y' = hg^{-1}x'$, so that $y' = ghg^{-1}x'$. In this perspective, the usual conjugation by $g$ tells us how the group action by $h$ transforms.
For the "passive transformation" perspective, I have to take some poetic license. In the $e$ "basis", $x$ has "coordinates" $x$, i.e. $x = ex$. We say $x$ has "coordinates" $x'$ in the $g$ "basis" if $x = gx'$. Now, how do we represent the action of $h$ in the $g$ basis? Set $y = hx$. We have $gy' = hgx'$, so $y' = (g^{-1}hg)x'$. Thus, we see that $h$ is given by $g^{-1}hg$ in the $g$ basis. This is the "reverse" conjugation you describe in your question.
So, which conjugation to choose? It's a matter of whether you think of the group action as turning the paper (active transformation) or turning your head (passive transformation). It may also be clear from how much poetic license I had to use in the passive case that the active transformation perspective is somehow more suited to group theory, though I can't begin to explain why.

@Downvoter: Please explain why you downvoted.  Just clicking down helps no one.

I certainly took some liberties with my answer. If it's more confusing or wrongheaded than it is helpful, I'll delete it. But I do think that the active transformation perspective at least is a helpful way to contextualize the importance of conjugation and offers one reason why it is usually written the way that it is.

And, in my defense, the passive transformation paragraph becomes pretty literal in the context of principal bundles for example.

I didn't downvote, but I'm close to it. You can't start with a left action, and then say "wow, doing things on the left works out so much easier".

I won't insist on one conjugation being more natural than the other. Happy to delete from my answer. It just seemed to me like an indication of why we traditionally prefer one to the other. But I offered this (admittedly strange) answer in terms of transformations because it seemed like the OP was familiar with linear algebra and reaching for a linear algebra metaphor.
